# JavaFX MediaPlayer loop

Tags: java, loops, video, javafx, media-player

I am working on a simpel game and I would like to have a video background. I first did this using a gif but this runs kind of slow. Now I created a video background using the mediaplayer and it works perfectly.
The video show without a problem.

The only problem I have is that the video does not want to loop. I tried every single aproache i found on the internet but nothing seems to work. 
The video always plays 1 time and then stops.
I am using the java JDK8. Windows 10, 64 bit.

This is my code:

```
Media media = new
Media(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("img/menu.mp4").toString());

MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
player.setAutoPlay(true);
player.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
```

All of this is inside a stackpane.

I have tried exporting the mp4 to flv but this does not work.

If anyone knows different ways to create a video background, everything is welcome.

**Edit:**
So far no luck, I was thinking of using:

```
player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                player.seek(Duration.ZERO);
            }
        });
```

But not even this works..

Comment: Have you tried playing your media after setting the cycle count, rather than before?

Comment: I am having the same problems and the strange fact is that it doesn't even reports an error or something , i have tried all the available set methods ... Java 8 Update 162.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From the `MediaPlayer` API:

Media playback commences at `startTime` and continues to `stopTime`. The interval defined by these two endpoints is termed a cycle with duration being the difference of the stop and start times. This cycle may be set to repeat a specific or indefinite number of times.

So you need to set `startTime` and `stopTime` before cycling works. For example (for a 5 second video):

```
player.setStartTime(Duration.seconds(0));
player.setStopTime(Duration.seconds(5));
```

Comment: The loop works! The only strange thing is: for a 5 sec video it works perfectly, but when my video is 10 sec long and I set the duration to 10 it freezes again.

Answer (score 5):

Probably it's a bit late but you forgot to play after seeking to duration zero.

```
player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            player.seek(Duration.ZERO);
            player.play();
        }
    });
```

It worked for me